# At what temperature does an envmon temperature alert trigger on a Cisco 2821

Tags: cisco, router

I'm having trouble finding the actual temperature point where a C2821 router will send out the trap for temperature. So far, I know the operating temperatures are from 0C to 40C. But at which point does it send the trap?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The thresholds will differ depending on the IOS, platform, and component in question.  The `show environment table` command will display the temperature thresholds.  When a threshold is crossed, a SNMP trap will be sent, if the router is configured to do so.

Here is a sample output:

```
R1#show environment table 
Sample Point      LowShut   LowCrit   LowWarn   HighWarn  HighCrit  HighShut  

I/O Cont Inlet                                  40C/104F  50C/122F  75C/167F  

I/O Cont Outlet                                 43C/109F  53C/127F  58C/136F  

NPE Inlet                                       75C/167F  75C/167F  75C/167F  

NPE Outlet                                      50C/122F  60C/140F  65C/149F  
+3.45 V           +2.42     +3.18                         +3.72     +4.48     
+5.15 V           +3.62     +4.80                         +5.49     +6.72     
+12.15 V          +8.54     +11.29                        +13.00    +15.85    
-11.95 V          -7.04     -9.52                         -14.38    -16.38
```

More information on the `environment` command can be found in the [Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals
Command Reference](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/command/Cisco_IOS_Configuration_Fundamentals_Command_Reference.pdf)
.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, trap will occur if it exceeds 65C. 
It cannot modify the command.

You can check the current temperature of the router with "show environment" command.